# Why is this inherited property expression ambiguous to the compiler?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, compiler-construction

Consider the following code:

```
using System;

namespace Sample
{
    public interface IGetOptions
    {
        string Options { get; }
    }

    public interface ISetOptions
    {
        string Options { set; }
    }

    public interface IOptions : IGetOptions, ISetOptions
    {
    }

    public class MyOptions : IOptions
    {
        public string Options { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new MyOptions();
            DoIt(a);
            Console.WriteLine(a.Options);
        }

        private static void DoIt(IOptions x)
        {
            x.Options = "test"; // Ambiguity between IGetOptions.Options and ISetOptions.Options
        }
    }
}
```

I have always understood properties to be syntax sugar for methods that return a value or assign a value. Given that the collision between `IGetOptions` and `ISetOptions` only exists by name, and each interface defines either a `get` or a `set`, **why can't the compiler resolve the ambiguity above?**

To me, it is obvious that `ISetOptions.set_Options` should be called here. If I were to change the code as follows, things would compile fine:

```
public interface IGetOptions
{
    string Options();
}

public interface ISetOptions
{
    void Options(string value);
}

public interface IOptions : IGetOptions, ISetOptions
{
}

public class MyOptions : IOptions
{
    public string Options() { return _options; }

    public void Options(string value) { _options = value; }

    private string _options;
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new MyOptions();
        DoIt(a);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Options());
    }

    private static void DoIt(IOptions x)
    {
        x.Options("test");
    }
}
```

This is what I always understood was happening under the hood with properties, so why can't the compiler make this jump for me?

I've also realized (what I consider) a workaround to this is to use the `new` keyword to hide the inherited properties. Using the first code snippet I posted, the following changes to `IOptions` make the code compile and work as expected:

```
public interface IOptions : IGetOptions, ISetOptions
{
    new string Options { get; set; }
}
```

This is also curious to me. Granted I've never purposefully used `new` to hide inherited properties or methods, but I thought this meant that `IOptions.Options` would be physically different from `IGetOptions.Options`, meaning methods that accept `IGetOptions` and evaluate `Options` would not see the same thing as `IOptions.Options` if that same object were also an `IOptions`. So the question here is: **how is it that the compiler is smart enough to collapse and relate the inherited properties that collide on name, but not smart enough to resolve the ambiguity above?**

Thanks in advance, and if anything needs clarification just let me know.

Comment: I see what you mean, but why even design something like that? Usually, when you don't control the interfaces and there is a name conflict, you implement one explicitly. Even if the compiler would take care of the ambiguity, your code would still look ambiguous to others.

Comment: Its not as easy as just choosing what you think is the best for this situation, the compiler has a very complicated set of rules of how it does member lookup, you can see it here in the specs `12.5 Member lookup` It just so happens this case falls under the last bullet point "*Otherwise, the lookup is ambiguous, and a binding-time error occurs.*" yeah sure they could probably spec their way around this, but they haven't. It might be the case that this breaks other rules, or the complexity outweighs the benefit, or they just couldn't be bothered, Maybe @EricLippert can jump in here

Answer (score 0):

The C# language specification does describe a concept of a "method group", allowing the compiler to delay the process of picking an individual method from a set of candidates based on additional criteria.

But the language specification does not currently have a similar concept for property groups. You'd also hit this error for `nameof(IOptions.Options)`, even though the nameof operation would have the same result no matter which `Options` property was used.

Why can't the compiler disambiguate these properties? The short answer is because it doesn't. Right now, the compiler expects to resolve a property name to an individual property, without caring about the context of how that property is used. A simple, testable process, that is sufficient to meet the current needs of developers.

If you wanted to add support to the compiler you'd need document how the language specification would change, then how the individual components of the compiler would change. Get buy-in from other compiler engineers and convince them that all this extra complexity is necessary. Then implement those changes and write unit tests to confirm exactly how it works... And nobody has done that yet.